# Can I see all units' health bars in real time in Age of Empires 2 HD?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

So I bought AOE2HD on Steam and have been playing a bit with friends.  One annoying thing I find is in a large battle I can't see the health of all units in real time so I have a difficult time managing my units.  In many other RTS games holding the `ALT` key shows a healthbar for all units on screen but this doesn't work in AOE2.

I've looked through options and Googled but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Steam Workshop is available for this game.  Not sure how customizable this is, but you might find a mod that does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in age of empires II.